# @NamedQuery override findAll in Spring Data Rest JpaRepository

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

Is there a way to override the findAll query executed by Spring Data Rest?

I need a way of filtering the results based on some specific criteria and it seems that using a `@NamedQuery` should be along the lines of what I'm looking for so I setup a test.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findAll", query="SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.username = 'test'"), 
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findNameEqualsTest", query="SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.username = 'test'")   
})
public class User implements Serializable, Identifiable<Long> { }
```

With this in place I would expect SDR to utilize my findAll() query (returning 1 result) but instead it executes the same old findAll logic (returning all results).

In my Repository I added:

```
@Repository
@RestResource(path = "users", rel = "users")
public interface UserJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    public Page<User> findNameEqualsTest(Pageable pageable);
}
```

and in this case it DOES pick up the provided `@NamedQuery`. So...

How should I go about overriding the default `findAll()` logic? I need to actually construct a complex set of criteria and apply it to the result set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can create your Implementation of your Repository interface, there is acouple section in

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.custom-implementations

Repository

```
   @Repository
    public interface PagLogRepository extends JpaRepository<PagLogEntity, Long>, PagLogCustomRepository {
```

Custom Interface

```
public interface PagLogCustomRepository {
PagLogEntity save(SalesForceForm salesForceForm) throws ResourceNotFoundException;
```

Custom implementation

```
public class PagLogRepositoryImpl implements PagLogCustomRepository {
@Override
    public PagLogEntity save(final SalesForceForm salesForceForm) throws ResourceNotFoundException {

        query = emEntityManager.createNamedQuery("findItemFileByDenormalizedSku", ItemFileEntity.class);
        query.setParameter("skuValue", rawSku);
```

Instead of override save make it with findAll, then you can create complex customization

Comment: Implemented and it's working. Was banging my head against the keyboard for a bit until I realized the importance of class names in this process.

Comment: Indeed, it is a very common problem, asked several times in SOverflow, tutorial should include a note there

Comment: As of Spring Data JPA 1.5 the custom implementation won't be necessary anymore to achieve this. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21751130/18122) for details.

Comment: that is wont be necessary it does not means the answer is not correct, but sounds great new version stuff

Answer (score 15):

In the upcoming version 1.5 (an RC is available in our milestone repositories) of Spring Data JPA you can simply redeclare the method in your repository interface and annotate it with `@Query` so that the execution as query method is triggered. This will then cause the named query to be looked up just as you're already used to from query methods:

```
interface UserJpaRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long> {

  @Query
  List<User> findAll();

  Page<User> findNameEqualsTest(Pageable pageable);
}
```

A few notes on your repository declaration:

- You don't need to annotate the interface with `@Repository`. That annotation doesn't have any effect at all here.
- Your `@RestResource` annotation configures the exporter in a way that will be the default anyway in Spring Data REST 2.0 (also in RC already). Ging forward, prefer `@RestRepositoryResource`, but as I said: the pluralization will be the default anyway.
- We generally don't recommend to extend the store specific interfaces but rather use `CrudRepository` or `PagingAndSortingRepository`.

Comment: Much appreciated, Oliver! I watched your Repositories Deepdive talk last night and that really helped clear some things up for me. I'll be making some changes today to better implement your best practices.