# Customize query for paging and sorting in Spring data rest

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I am using Spring data rest and am trying to customize the query for two of the overloaded `findAll` methods using `@Query`.  However, when I attempt this I receive this error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous search mapping detected. Both public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page courses.CourseRepository.findAll(org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable) and public abstract java.lang.Iterable courses.CourseRepository.findAll(org.springframework.data.domain.Sort) are mapped to /findAll! Tweak configuration to get to unambiguous paths!

When these methods are called the URL does not contain `/findAll` by convention. A URL for retrieving unsorted courses (but using paging) is

> http://localhost:8080/v1/courses

and sorting is

> http://localhost:8080/v1/courses?sort=title

Here's the relevant code, which is fairly straightforward:

```
public interface CourseRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Course, Long> {

  @Override
  @Query("SELECT c FROM Course c WHERE c.visible = 'Yes'")
  Page<Course> findAll(Pageable pageable);

  @Override
  @Query("SELECT c FROM Course c WHERE c.visible = 'Yes'")
  Iterable<Course> findAll(Sort sort);
}
```

I've also attempted using an `@NamedQuery` on the Course entity with the same error message.

EDIT:

I have discovered that the `findAll(Pageable pageable)` method has Sorting 'built-in', however it does not sort the results. When I hit the following URL and attempt to sort by title the results are clearly not sorted by title. However, without the custom `@Query` the results are sorted.

> http://localhost:8080/v1/courses?sort=title

Comment: Do you have issue only for not sorting? can you send the code piece for calling the repository method Page<Course> findAll(Pageable pageable);. Actually where you would configure for sorting.

Comment: @PremkumarMathivanan since it is Spring Data Rest the call to findAll is behind-the-scenes.  I do not have specific code that calls that method.

Comment: Can you confirm did I answer you close by?

Answer (score 4):

Try

`http://localhost:8080/v1/courses?sort=title,asc`

`http://localhost:8080/v1/courses?sort=title,desc`

Or if you are using older Spring version, then take a look at this doc:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/1.1.x/reference/html/paging-chapter.html

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are trying overloading `findAll` method of Spring-Data. This can be achieved only by `CustomRepository`.

Here is the useful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21734149/namedquery-override-findall-in-spring-data-rest-jparepository) for you to guide about creating `CustomRepository`.

You can defined a class with the custom methods for tweaking Spring-Data's method based on the need.

Spring documentation [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.custom-implementations) for the same