# Spring Data Rest Custom Controller

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have requirement where in which i need to override the delete functionality from the rest Resource using a custom controller.here is the code for restResource

```
@RepositoryRestResource
    public interface SampleRepository extends JpaRepository<Sample,Long>{
List<Sample> findBySampleNumber(@Param("sampleNumber") String sampleNumber);
    }
```

i have created a  a custom controller which overides only delete fuctionality

```
@RepositoryRestController
@RequestMapping("/api/samples")
public class SampleController{
    @Autowired
    SampleRepository sampleRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    @ResponseBody
    public void delete(@PathVariable Long id) {
        //do some custom logic here
        //then delete the sample
        //sampleRepository.delete(id);

    }
```

However if now try to make a `GET api/samples/1(someId)` or look up some search functionality on the RepositoryRestResource, I see the following error

`"description": "Request method 'GET' not supported"`

is there way to override only one HTTP verb have the rest of the functionality coming up from the repository.

However if i comment `public void delete` from the controller i am able to access all the crud and Search operations

Has Anyone encountered such an issue

I am using `SPRING_DATA_REST-2.5.1-Release`

Comment: not exactly a duplicate, but the solution is the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21734149/namedquery-override-findall-in-spring-data-rest-jparepository

Answer (score 8):

You need to define your controller as

```
@RepositoryRestController
public class SampleController{
    @Autowired
    SampleRepository sampleRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/samples/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public void delete(@PathVariable Long id) {

    }
```

As well as spring data provide different events to perform before and after the domain create,save and delete.

Refer http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#events

Comment: @Nlrav Modi  I thought we use the events t do some kind of entity validations and check if the bean meets some criteria

Comment: yes, but I don't know what is your custom logic, So I had given another solution about an event. You can accept the answer if your problem solved.

Answer (score 7):

You have to use the RequestMapping annotation at the [method level only](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-535).

Comment: Thanks for pointing Out the link [link] http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.4.0.M1/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.overriding-sdr-response-handlers. This Resolved it